# Missing PDB file and referenced output

Tags: .net, debugging, pdb-files, binaries

My .Net Application, A, has a reference to library B. Library B has a reference to Library C. When I rebuild A (in debug mode), its output directory contains me the B.DLL and B.PDB files, but only the C.DLL file. C.PDB is missing, or rather it is not being copied from its project's debug folder.

In fact, looking at B's output directory, the C.PDB is missing there, too. C.PDB is, however, in C's output directory, at least.

Why might this be and how can I correct it?

**Update:**
It turns out it's not just that PDB file. The entire library isn't being updated in output directories of those that reference it. What would cause that sort of behavior? Could it be a bug with visual studio?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. What version of Visual Studio are you running? And have you tried doing a project clean + rebuild?

Comment: 2010 Premium. Clean and rebuild doesn't help. It's really weird. I checked every project setting between B and C, and they're identical, yet B's PDB file gets copied to other debug folders, while C's does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had a bad reference from B to C. I did a search for the DLL that wasn't getting updated, and noticed two instances of that had the same date as the out of date instances. I deleted them, which broke the reference in B. Replacing the reference, all appears to work now, including C.PDB.